# snapshot testing unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to use snapshot testing error

```html
import React from "react";
import LandingPage from "../components/landingpage/LandingPage";


describe("the Landing page should not change", () => {
  it("Landing page matches the snapshot", () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<LandingPage />).toJSON();

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

But when I try to run jest I get this error

SyntaxError: C:\Users\ryan1\Downloads\Capstone\Ovals\src\unitTesting\snapshot.test.js: Unexpected token (17:33)

```
  15 | describe("the Landing page should not change", () => {
  16 |   it("Landing page matches the snapshot", () => {
> 17 |     const tree = renderer.create(<LandingPage />).toJSON();
     |                                  ^
  18 | 
  19 |     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  20 |   });
```

Does anyone know whats wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: If you are using babel, to transform JSX to JS, should this file be `snapshot.test.jsx` so it can be picked up?